# Google translate website with Https

Tags: https, google-translate

Google translate works perfectly on my website but when I need to add a correction I have this problem in console:

```
was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://translate.google.com/gen204?client=te-alt&althighlight=1': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://translate.google.com/translate_suggestion': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.
```

How to force Google translate to use HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

When you refer to `translate.google.com` every time in your script, ensure that **you** refer to it using **https** and the response would be in **https** too. Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i hope you can get idea about  force website from HTTP to HTTPS .If your site uses authentication then it must also use HTTPS for the life of the session
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/should-we-force-user-to-https-on-website

Answer (score 0):

When your page is loaded via HTTPS, the default security behaviour is to block anything loaded via HTTP.

To be synthetic:

- HTTP in HTTP: no problem;
- HTTPS in HTTP: no problem;
- HTTPS in HTTPS: no problem;
- HTTP in HTTPS: **possible security flaw**.

If you wish to spare yourself the trouble of determining which protocol to use, remove it from the G translate: write your URL `//translate.google.com/...` (without specifying the protocol). Your browser should automatically complete the URL with the same protocol as your calling page.

The other choice would be to always load Google Translate via HTTPS.